# phpunit setup class testing

Tags: pdo, phpunit

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class Base {
    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    protected $_dbh;
    protected $_logFile;

    public function __construct($dbh, $logFile) {
        $this->_dbh = $dbh;
        $this->_logFile = $logFile;
    }
}

.............

class bbb extends Base {


public function smth() {
    $this->_addTracToDB([....]);
}

private function _addTracToDB($data) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (t_time, t_priority)
            VALUES(:t_time, :t_priority)";

    $query = $this->_dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([
        ':t_time' => $data['timestamp'],
        ':t_priority' => $data['priority'],
    ]);
}

public function smth2() {
    $sql = 'selct * from table2';
    $query = $this->_dbh->query($sql);
        return $query->fetchAll();
}

}
```

Tan i try to test it with:

```
class mockPDO extends \PDO
{
    public function __construct ()
    {}

}

class ChinaBaseTest extends DbTestAbstract {
    protected $pdo;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->pdo = $this->getMock('mockPDO', array('query'), array('sqlite:memory')); // *<-- error here*
//      $this->pdo->expects($this->any())
//          ->method('query')
//          ->will($this->returnValue(new \PDOStatement()));
        $this->pdo->expects($this->any())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new \PDOStatement()));

//      $foo->query('SELECT * FROM users;'); // instantiated PDOStatement class will be returned
//      var_dump($foo->getAvailableDrivers()); // take note that methods originally declared in PDO class is available too

        $tableNames = array('guestbook');
        $dataSet = $this->getConnection()->createDataSet($tableNames);
    }

    protected function getDataSet() {
        return $this->createFlatXmlDataSet(__DIR__ . '/_data/myFlatXmlFixture.xml');
    }

    protected function _getDataFile($fileName) {
        return file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/_data/' . $fileName);
    }

    public function testParseSingle() {
        $bbb  = new bbb ($this->pdo, LOG_DIR . 'common.log');
        $result = $bbb->smth($this->_getDataFile('787.log'));
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($result));
        $this->assertArrayHasKey(0, $result);
        $result = $result[0];

        $this->assertEquals(mktime(11, 39, 24, 9, 10, 2014), $result['timestamp']);
        ......
    }


}
```

But receivean error:

```
ReflectionException : Class Mock_mockPDO_b630d3bd does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments
 D:\........\myTest.php:26
```

This line: $this->pdo = $this->getMock('mockPDO',

So may be i`m on wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor does not take arguments:

```
class mockPDO extends \PDO
{
    public function __construct ($arg)
    {}

}
```

---

```
$this->pdo = $this->getMock('mockPDO',            //the class name to mock
                            array('query'),         //the methods to mock
                            array('sqlite:memory'));//arguments to pass to constructor
```